# Making an object model for Couchbase Lite 2 in Swift

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite

In our app we are currently using CBLModel to model all our database objects. This works great as long as we stick with Couchbase Lite 1.4. I would like to upgrade to Couchbase Lite 2.X, but I can't find any similar object model. All I have found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49950047/9102302) from two years ago stating that the Couchbase team are not working on this.

So how can I implement a model for Couchbase Lite in Swift? Would it be possible to use codable for this?

Comment: Questions like "what is the best way to do X" are off-topic because they are opinion-based. What is "best" is subjective. Check out the [help] for more info.

Comment: Thank you @TylerH for pointing that out! I have updated the question.

Comment: swift codables is probably the best option.